# Negative of a clause or phrase at the outset of an enumeration + "or" / "and no"

Tags: conjunctions, negation

[Fowler reads](https://books.google.es/books?id=mSjnCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA632&dq=%22When%20the%20negative%20of%20a%20clause%20or%20phrase%20has%20appeared%20at%20the%20outset%20of%20an%20enumeration%2C%20and%20a%20disjunctive%20conjunction%20is%20needed%2C%20or%20is%20generally%20better%20than%20nor.%22&hl=es&pg=PA632#v=onepage&q=%22When%20the%20negative%20of%20a%20clause%20or%20phrase%20has%20appeared%20at%20the%20outset%20of%20an%20enumeration,%20and%20a%20disjunctive%20conjunction%20is%20needed,%20or%20is%20generally%20better%20than%20nor.%22&f=false)

> When the negative of a clause or phrase has appeared at the outset of
> an enumeration, and a disjunctive conjunction is needed, **or** is
> generally better than **nor**. The initial negative carries through to
> all the enumerated elements—e.g.:
>
> • “*There have been **no** bombings **or** armed attacks by one side
> against the other.*”
>
> Sometimes the best solution is **and no** —e.g.:
>
> • “*Although he has almost **no** name recognition **and no** political
> cash, Unruhe appears undaunted*.”

When and why is **and no** a better solution than **or** ?

Comment: Using ***and no*** instead of ***or*** in the cited contexts (both are "acceptable" in both examples) adds a degree of ***emphasis***. That's to say, to some extent, *no X or Y* simply lumps "X + Y" together and asserts that they don't exist, but *no X **and no** Y* calls attention more forcefully to the fact that not only is X not present - ***Y isn't present either***. But it's a very fine point that wouldn't necessarily be honoured or recognised by all native speakers.

Comment: (The longer and more explicit form ***and no*** might also be more suitable as an "aid to parsing" in contexts where the non-existent element "X" is a particularly long text string, if the reader might otherwise struggle to recognise exactly what ***or*** refers back to, and/or forget to "propagate" the negation of X to the negation of Y.)